High CPU Usage Linux
I wanted to ask, so currently I got my application running on Linux VM, I saw my java application consume 90% CPU usage and more, I tried to investigate whats happening on my java application, tried some thread dump according to some sites, and this is what I get.
"VM Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=243902377.68ms elapsed=921633.36s tid=0x00007fcbc4194800 nid=0x3ecd58 runnable
It has the same result when I executed with top -H CLI on linux.

below i attached the link for my threaddump file, i hope it's helpful to identify what making it consuming high CPU.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/e4u2yggxqx8dudafyqkkk/thread_dump_2024-12-30-10_22_24.txt?rlkey=2av255umckbyvn4yn7ittgj7v&st=61ucqz0n&dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/58niyrv9te752tgacyybe/thread_usage_4115788_2024-12-30-10_22_24.txt?rlkey=5copl2d1qy06rut9rqygglaag&st=kuwgpaks&dl=0
Do you have any idea how to solve this VM Thread high CPU Usage?
Thank you.

So your program is either doing a lot of computations in which case this is expected, or the program is stuck in some kind of loop in which case you need to debug the program to see what it is doing. Either way we can't help any more with the information you have shown us.

It's a valid question (don't worry about haters). For cpu usage in jvm, devs use a jvm profiler. Start with the free one in the jdk called "jconsole" (sibling of java in bin folder). You then attach to the jvm (perhaps remotely in your case) and look for cpu profiling or recording. This would give you an idea of which threads and code is hot. It's s skill worth developing. Good luck.

I meant "jvisualvm", not jconsole.
